# Telerik Kendo MVC Scheduler - Can't move events

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui, telerik, scheduler

I have a problem with the scheduler.
I'm using the ASP.NET MVC module, but moving events are not working as they should.

If I want to move non-all-day event, it does not work. It does not move, and I get an error like this:

> kendo.all.js:96953 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'startOffset' of null.

But, the weird part comes next:
If I try to move an all-day event, I can move non-all-day events, but I can't move where I want. It will jump to the next day or the previous day. It depends on how I moved the all-day events. 
(So basically when I move an all-day event 1 day forward, the normal event will move one day forward, no matter where I want to move.)
Also if I move all-day events, I see them transparent when I'm moving them, but this effect is not present when I try to move non-all-day events.

I suspect having different time zones in the project, I will check them after I sent this post.

Also, the Application Insights gives me this warning:

> CannotSerializeObjectNonSerializable message:"Attempting to serialize
>   an object which does not implement ISerializable"
>   props:"{name:baseData}"

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out: if you experience similar problems, the _layout.cshtml may contain some css code which hides/transforms the scheduler (or its rows), therefore the kendo jquery won't be able to find the events.